# Minimizing a nonelementary integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

I have the integral
$$
\int _{-1}^1\left(|x|-\frac{x^2 \left(x^2 \left(c_1 x^2+c_2\right)+c_3\right)}{x^2 \left(c_4 x^2+c_5\right)+c_6}\right)^2\mathrm{d}x
$$

which I express in Mathematica code as

```
Clear[c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6];
f[x_]:=((RealAbs[x]-(x^2*(x^2*(c1*x^2+c2)+c3))/(x^2*(c4*x^2+c5)+c6))^2)

f[x]
HoldForm[Integrate[f[x], {x, -1, 1}]]
```

How can I search for real values of $c_i$ that minimize the value of this nonelementary integral?

Comment: as it should be the same as minimizing the norm of $Abs [x]$ and $(x^2 (c + x^2 (b + a x^2)))/(m + x^2 (v + d x^2))$,how about using of `NonlinearModelFit`? `expr = (x^2 (c + x^2 (b + a x^2)))/(m + x^2 (v + d x^2));
input = x;
cofs = {a, b, c, d, m, v};
NonlinearModelFit[
 {#, Abs[#]} & /@ Range[-1, 1, .01],
 expr, cofs, input]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to be more specific refering to the answer of @Yusuf, try:

```
func[x_, a_, b_, c_, d_, m_, v_] = 
     (-((x^2 (c + x^2 (b + a x^2)))/(m + x^2 (v + d x^2))) + 
     Abs[x])^2;

nint[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[func[x, a, b, c, d, m, v], {x, -1, 1}]

NMinimize[nint[a, b, c, d, m, v], 
   {{a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 1}, {d, 0, 1}, {m, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}}]

(*   {0.0000131187, {a -> 1.25015, b -> 2.12136, c -> 0.0859803, d -> 2.75847, 
          m -> 0.00319823, v -> 0.680549}}   *)
```

But you have no warranty, that this is a global minimum. Use starting values for the parameters, that make sense according to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This Mathematica code determines values of $c_i$ that yield an integral equal to approximately $0.0000131187$

```
Clear[c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6];
f[x_] := ((RealAbs[
      x] - (x^2*(x^2*(c1*x^2 + c2) + c3))/(x^2*(c4*x^2 + c5) + c6))^2)

f[x]

vals = NMinimize[
   NIntegrate[f[x], {x, -1, 1}],
    {c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6}];
vals

("
vals: 
{0.0000131187, {c1 -> 73766.2, c2 -> 125174., c3 -> 5073.46, 
  c4 -> 162767., c5 -> 40156.9, c6 -> 188.723}}
")
```